# Create Dimensions from edge of wall, to sides of openings, to other edge of wall

Tags: revit-api, revit, revit-2015

I've been struggling with this issue off and on for the better part of a year.
As the title says, i wish to dimension from one side of a wall, to both sides of openings (door openings), then terminate at the other end of the wall (vertically and horizontally). I also wish to dimension to all families hosted in the wall, but i have been able to accomplish this using ScottWilson's voodo magic helper class. Found Here: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/04/stable-reference-string-magic-voodoo.html

```
foreach (ElementId ele in selSet) {
            FamilyInstance fi = doc.GetElement(ele) as FamilyInstance;
            Reference reference = ScottWilsonVoodooMagic.GetSpecialFamilyReference(fi,ScottWilsonVoodooMagic.SpecialReferenceType.CenterLR,doc);
            refs.Append(reference);
            pts[i] = ( fi.Location as LocationPoint ).Point;
            i++;
        }

        XYZ offset = new XYZ(0,0,4);
        Line line = Line.CreateBound( pts[0]+offset, pts[selSet.Count - 1]+offset );


        using( Transaction t = new Transaction( doc ) )
        {
            t.Start( "dimension embeds" );
            Dimension dim = doc.Create.NewDimension(doc.ActiveView, line, refs );
            t.Commit();
        }
```

The problem lies in determining the appropriate stable references to the wall faces. I am able to find all faces on a wall, but this gives me 100+ faces to sort through.

If anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated!

Side note: The closest of gotten is using a casting a ray trace through my panel, then using a reference intersector method to determine references. But i'm really struggling with implementation: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/12/retrieving-wall-openings-and-sorting-points.html

Answer (score 1):

These two posts should provide more than enough to solve all your issues:

- [Dimension walls by iterating their faces](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/02/dimension-walls-by-iterating-faces.html)
- [Dimension walls by shooting a ray](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/02/dimension-walls-using-findreferencesbydirection.html)

Basically, you need to obtain references to the faces or edges that you wish to attach the dimensioning to. These references can be obtained in several ways. Two common and easy approaches are:

- Retrieve the [element geometry using the option `ComputeReferences` set to true](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2018.1/d7da6de4-74a9-60e2-826f-698a5730d0a8.htm) and extract the specific face required.
- [Shoot a ray through the model to determine the required element and its face using the `2017
  ReferenceIntersector Class`](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2018.1/36f82b40-1065-2305-e260-18fc618e756f.htm).

Comment: Hi, I didn't check if these links have been scanned by the web archive. If they haven't and the site goes offline, your answer is useless for people who visit this in the future. Please consider editing and highlighting the specific parts that answer the question. Cheers

Comment: i added brief descriptions of the two approaches covered in full by the two blog posts. i am sorry that the internet is flawed and impermanent. that really sucks.